# Как передать значение input из одного в другой?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

1 input надо запомнить значение и передать его в 2 input

```
<input type="text"
                class="form-control niki"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              />
```

2 input должен принять значение

```
<input
                type="email"
                class="form-control niks"
                id="exampleInputEmail2"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                readonly
              />
```

работаю во vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке - Передать, В вопросе - Запомнить и передать.
Если правильно понял - возможно такой вариант Вам подойдет
https://codepen.io/VMax/pen/GRyJXwx

```js
function snd(exampleInputEmail1, exampleInputEmail2) {
  document.getElementById(exampleInputEmail2).value = document.getElementById(
    exampleInputEmail1
  ).value;
}
```

```html
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">exampleInputEmail1</label>
<input type="text" oninput="snd('exampleInputEmail1','exampleInputEmail2')" class="form-control niki" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />

<br><br>

<label for="exampleInputEmail2">exampleInputEmail2</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control niks" id="exampleInputEmail2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

Если уже используете `vue`, то советую избегать прямого манипулирования `DOM` элементами, в тех случаях, когда этого можно избежать.
Vue расширяет стандартный HTML синтаксис шаблона, который позволяет нам декларативно описывать **вывод HTML на основе состояния JavaScript**.

На основании изложенного, если вам нужно просто продублировать значение одного поля в другое, имеет смысл назначить им одну модель (`v-model="input1"`) и тогда при изменении значения в первом поле, второе поле будет автоматически обновлено.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      input1: '',
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="input1" />
  <input type="email" v-model="input1" readonly />
</div>
```